# Chrome extension rich notifications not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an **chrome-extension** that i want to use the new rich notifications.  I'm trying to implement the following:

```
var opt = {
            type: "basic",
            title: "New message from " + sBuffer[0] + ":",
            message: sBuffer[2],
            iconUrl: getUserIcon(sBuffer[0])
        };
        chrome.notifications.create("",opt,function(){});
```

But no matter what i do, i get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined`

I went into `chrome://flags` and set everything with 'notifications' in it to enabled...  I'm running chrome 31.0.1650.57 m.

This works fine:

```
var notification =  webkitNotifications.createNotification(
    getUserIcon(sBuffer[0]),
    "New message from " + sBuffer[0] + ":",
    sBuffer[2]
);
notification.show();
```

It's not pretty, but it works (the icon is tiny even though it's a high-res image...  ***Is there any way i can make the image icon bigger?***)

BTW, i've got the notifications permission in my manifest.

Thanks,Dave

**EDIT:  Included manifest**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "Notifier",
 "description": "This extension will listen the the JS on the page and popup notifications",
 "version": "0.1",

 "permissions": [
"background","notifications"
],
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://MY_WEB_SITE"],
  "js": ["Notifier.js"]
}
]
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have permissions set in your manifest (which you prob should include). Also `id` should be unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to access the **`chrome.notifications` API** from a content script. But it is not available for content scripts, so you'll need to create the notification in the background page.

If you need to pass specific data to be displayed in the notification, you can use **[Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#simple)** to communicate between the content script and the background page.
E.g.:

```
/* In content script */
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    from: sBuffer[0],
    body: sBuffer[2]
});

/* In background page */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {
    /* Verify the message's format */
    (msg.from !== undefined) || return;
    (msg.body !== undefined) || return;

    /* Create and show the notification */
    // ...your notification creation code goes here
    // (replace `sBuffer[0]`/`sBuffer[2]` with `msg.from`/`msg.body`) 
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "background-page"? Is it a .js-file that must be included via `<link>`?

Comment: By background page I mean the [background-or event-page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages). Not sure what `.js` file you are talking about and how `<link>` comes into play.